# Bizarre Adobe Captivate 9 Internet Explorer 9 HTML 5 button issue

Tags: html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, adobe-captivate

I am working on a project using the latest version of Adobe Captivate (version 9) to develop HTML5 modules, and I have just learned their LMS (I don't know the name) only uses Internet Explorer 9 (I know, I know).  For what it's worth, pretty much everything works or there has been a workaround that makes it look like it's working.

However, there is one rather odd issue that has eluded me: on the last slide of each module, there needs to be a close button that closes the module.  While I have been able to get this to work on newer web browsers, for whatever reason in IE9, I have to **DOUBLE-CLICK** in order for this to work.  It doesn't matter if I'm using the "Exit" action within Captivate or executing Javascript to do the same thing.  For whatever reason, I have to double click.

Here's where things get a little weird.  The modules also have a playbar at the bottom, which includes an [X] button which will close the lesson (yes, I know that's redundant; it wasn't my idea), but I only need to click on it once for it to work.  Why does my close button need to be double-clicked to close the module?  (Yes, I know there is a check-box that can require the button to be double-clicked, but it isn't checked; trust me, I've looked!)  Again, for what it's worth, I do have other buttons in the modules and they work with a single click.

I know just enough javascript to know not mess with the output files, and my programming co-worker doesn't know what to make of it either, so I'm turning to you fellows to see if someone has something we haven't thought of.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I was able to come up with a solution, for those of you who stumble across this.  What I ended up doing was replacing the buttons with weblinks.  I created a shape, put some text in it, then turned that text into a link.  For the Close button, I simply linked it to "goodbye.html" which is within the export folder, and the reporting stuff still worked.  For whatever reason, this link didn't need to be double-click like the button did.  I don't know why, but it works.

Because I also had the same problem with a button that was supposed to restart the lesson, I also learned that links can be used for more than just web addresses.  Instead, I was able to "link" it to the first slide by choosing the "Slide" option and things worked great!

So there you go, a solution to this weird and specific problem.